# TCP/IP connection refused when trying to connect to 4G GSM Module via AT commands

Tags: tcp, serversocket, gsm, tcplistener

I've been trying to access a TCP server from my 4g GSM Module via AT commands.I hosted a test tcp server in socket test application, add a new inbound rule regarding the tcp Port in Windows Firewall advanced setting and also i opened a virtual server allowing the tcp port which i configured as server in the modem menu also. The server is nowhere to seen in the gsm module. Then I checked the canyouseeme.org website. It says that the connection is refused.

Am I missing anything.Please Help

Comment: It is very difficult to help you, as plenty basic information are missing. 1) Which Telit modem are you using? 2) What AT commands are you sending in order to estabilish the TCP connection? 3) What errors do you get? 4) Are you able to connect to different servers? 5) Are you able to estabilish the same connection using telnet or putty?

Comment: Hi Roberto,
The Modem which I'm using is Dlink DIR 600M.  The AT command used after net establishment is AT+CIPOPEN. The SIM Module is SIM7600IE. so i tried with the gsm module and there is no data coming to server. Then I did an access check from other computer and SocketTest also. But the connection is refused error is coming

Comment: If you can't access using PC tools, the problem obviously isn't in the modem sim7600. And from the modem can you connect to another tcp server?

Comment: Can you please post the complete connection attempt so that we can reproduce the attempt and help you in making it successful?